# Separating out the final term from a sum of sums

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I am trying to separate the following term:

$$ x_{k_1, \dots,k_n} $$

From the following summation:

$$ \sum_{a_1 = 0}^{k_1} \dots \sum_{a_n = 0}^{k_n} x_{a_1, \dots, a_n} .$$

I want to split the summation so that I have a sum (or likely a series of sums) that calculates all the terms except $ x_{k_1, \dots,k_n} $, and then $ + \text{ } x_{k_1, \dots,k_n} $ separated from the sum. In other words:

$$  \sum_{a_1 = 0}^{k_1} \dots \sum_{a_n = 0}^{k_n} x_{a_1, \dots, a_n} = \left( \sum_{a_1 = 0}^{?} \dots \sum_{a_n = 0}^{?} x_{a_1, \dots, a_n} + \dots \right)+x_{k_1, \dots, k_n}  . $$

EDIT: For example, if there was just one sum rather than $n$ summations, it would be easy to separate out that final term, like so:

$$ \sum_{a_1=0}^{k_1} x_{a_1} = \sum_{a_1=0}^{k_1 -1} x_{a_1} +x_{k_1} $$

but in the case of $n$ summations, I'm not sure how to separate it out.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is not simple. You need to do it in 2 dimension first and expand to n dimension by induction.